# Parcel 2.0 PostCSS, how to disable media queries transformation

Tags: media-queries, transformation, postcss, parcel

I'm using Parcel 2.0.

I noticed that on iPhone 13, iOS Safari version 15.x and 16.x, the media queries are completely ignored.

After some test I realised that Safari ignores media queries when they are using '<' and '>' operators instead of 'min-width' and 'max-width'.

The original css syntax is this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .my-container {
      background-color: rosybrown;
    }
}
```

After Parcel's build, this media queries is converted in:

```
@media screen and (width <= 750px) {
  .my-container {
    background-color: #bc8f8f;
  }
}
```

How can I disable this media queries conversion from '**max-width**' to '**<=**'?

I tried to check on postCSS documentation on how to disable this transformation, without finding anything, then to add polyfills with browserslist:

`"browserslist": [     "last 15 versions, not dead" ],`

but nothing to do, those properties are always converted from 'max-width' to '<='

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I first tried to install this plugin for PostCSS, but it did not work form me:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss-media-minmax

Then I followed this approach, it did work for me:
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/9139

N.B. as written, notice that it works only during build:
"Still, it only works for parcel build, not just parcel."